# What is the cardinality of non-integer rationals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm confused on the cardinality of non-integer rationals. Can somebody please help me? All I know is that the cardinality of real numbers is $\aleph_1$ while the cardinality of all integers is $\aleph_0$.

Comment: But the cardinality of the set of rationals is $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You will bet more useful help if you make clearer what you know. Please edit the question to tell us whether you know the cardinality of the rationals. If not, can you look that up?

Comment: Side note.  Do not write $\aleph_1$ for the cardinal of the reals: that is assuming the Continuum Hypothesis... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis

Answer (score 3):

The cardinality of the rationals is $\aleph_0$, the size of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. they are countably infinite. As $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is countable. As it is not finite, it is countably infinite, i.e. $\mathsf{card}(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z})=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 0):

It would be countably infinite.   The rationals are countable.  $\aleph_0$, if you like...